# PCRE_MULTILINE "m" modifier

Tags: php, regex, pcre, newline

I agree with the [PHP Modifiers Reference](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php) in the 'm' modifier description that says:

When this modifier is set, the "start of line" and "end of line" constructs match immediately following or immediately before any newline in the subject string, respectively, as well as at the very start and end.

I'm learning regular expressions and this example is a little confusing:

```
<?php echo preg_replace("/^[\s]*$/m","<p>","with.\n\n\n\t \nTherefor"); ?>
```

It ends up with:

> "with.\n
>
> \nTherefor"

But I put mentally the '^' and '$' metacharacters like previously said.
(^,$=imaginal positions)

> ^with.$\n^$\n^$\n^\t $\n^Therefor$

And reading the regex:

A start of line followed or not by one space character ([ \t\r\n]) followed by the end of the line.

But the regex engine takes from the second '^' to the fourth '$', eating up the '\n'. Shouldn't it be like this?:

(^,$=imaginal positions)

> ```
> ^with.$\n <br/>
> ^(no space character)$\n <br/>
> ^(no space character)$\n <br/>
> ^(\t )$\n <br/>
> ^Therefor$
>
>
> with.\n <br/>
> <p>\n <br/>
> <p>\n <br/>
> <p>\n <br/>
> Therefor
> ```

It is supposed that the regex runs toward the right.
Why does the regex seem lookahed the '\n'?

Because it matches at the point ^(no space character)$ and then follows...' \n '.

Comment: I understand your concern, but not your confusion. In fact your depiction with the imaginary ^ and $ is the best explanation I've ever seen. Your `^` can only match *after* the first `\n` (because the *new* line begins *after* the line break), and the `$` only matches until the last possible `\n` (line end *before* line break).

Comment: yeah but it supose that match when found one start of line followed or not by a space character and inmediately a end of line, i dont understand why the newline match.

Comment: Uh ok. You wanted multiple `<p>` breaks. Your regex combines multiple empty lines, because `\s` does match all whitespace -> *including `\n` newlines*. `\s` is equivalent to writing `[\r\n\t\h\v ]` or something.

Comment: yeah but not in order, i think

Comment: the regex is like look ahead the new line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This regex seems to combine multiple lines...

But you can avoid this, by using the `U` modifier xor adding a `?` to `*`, so that it's not longer greedy:

```
echo preg_replace("/^[\s]*$/mU","<p>","with.\n\n\n\t \nTherefor");
echo preg_replace("/^[\s]*?$/m","<p>","with.\n\n\n\t \nTherefor");
```

Comment: yeah it works, but i dont know if you understand why if match previusly ^$ , the regex match new line too, i cant explain lol

Comment: What do you mean by "xor"?